# Dynamic data from csv and response in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm able to correctly extract the data from csv but in response it is saying Invalid data format

I'm  dynamically calling the data from csv .I'm able to extract the data correctly from csv, it is showing up on my JMeter also, and I'm receiving the token also but in response it is saying invalid data format.

Answer (score 0):

If the system under test says "invalid data format" most probably your request is built incorrectly and server cannot understand this.

1. Record the request using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)
2. Perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of dynamic parameters
3. Once you verify that request works and doing what it is supposed to be doing start substituting recorded hard-coded values with the data from CSV in form of [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) one by one. Use [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request details and compare them with the successful request. It might be the case the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is not set up correctly and instead of variable value you're sending the placeholder or you need to surround the variable with quotation marks or something like this.